# How to prove this combinatorial identity $\sum^{m-1}_{k=0}\binom{n+m-1}{k} = \sum^{m-1}_{k=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(2^{m-k-1}\right)$?

Tags: probability, combinatorial-proofs

Can you please explain to me or give me some hints on how to prove the following identity?$$\sum^{m-1}_{k=0}\binom{n+m-1}{k} = \sum^{m-1}_{k=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(2^{m-k-1}\right)$$
where $m, n$ are positive integers.

I came across this when I was solving a problem on probability. Just for your reference, the problem, translated into English, is as follows:

A and B are two gamblers. In each round of a game, they have equal chances to win (that is, the probability of winning is 1/2). Before the game started, they had agreed that the one that wins a certain number of rounds first can get all the money (say, 1000 pounds). However, the gambling is interrupted for some reason. At this point, gambler A has to win $n$ more rounds in order to get all the money, while gambler B has to win $m$ more rounds. The question is, if it is impossible for the game to go on, how much of the 1000 pounds should be given to gamblers A and B, respectively? (The distribution of the money should be based on the probability of winning if the game had not been interrupted).

Using two different ways of thinking, we can obtain two different expressions for the probability of gambler A winning the money (had the game not been interrupted). They are:

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+1}+\binom{n+1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}+\cdots+\binom{n+m-2}{m-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+m-1}$$
and
$$\left(\binom{n+m-1}{0}+\binom{n+m-1}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+m-1}$$

By comparing these two expressions, we can obtain the identity that I am asking about. I am amazed when I see these two totally different expressions which always give the same value. I am wondering if there are simple ways to transform one side into the other. If not, how can we prove this identity? Thank you for your generous help!

Comment: This probably follows from $\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k} = 2^k$

Comment: For your motivating problem, which is truly classical (Fermat) see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points).

Comment: @John Lei - what was your reasoning for the second expression?

Comment: @Rohit Pandey - If the game was not interrupted, it could go on for at most n+m-1 more rounds before A or B won. Now assume the game actually goes on for exactly n+m-1 rounds even if someone already wins the game in an earlier round (the subsequent rounds do not affect the result of the game). With this, any subsequent rounds can be thought of as a sequence of "A"s and "B"s of length (n+m-1), where "A" means A wins that round and "B" means B wins that round. For example, "AAB" means A wins the first two rounds, then B wins the third round.

Comment: @Rohit Pandey - The claim is that the probability of A winning the game is the same as the probability that a randomly generated sequence of length (n+m-1) contains no more than (m-1) “B”s. For a simple illustration, let n = 2 and m = 2. For A to win the game, the winning order is one of: A-A (prob. = 1/4), A-B-A (prob. = 1/8), B-A-A (prob. = 1/8). On the other hand, consider all sequences of length 3 that entail A’s winning the game: AAA, AAB, ABA, and BAA. Notice P(AAA) + P(AAB) = P(A-A) = 1/4, P(ABA) = P(A-B-A) = 1/8, and P(BAA) = P(B-A-A) = 1/8.

Comment: @Rohit Pandey - More generally, we have, P(a1-a2-a3-...-ak) = Sum of P(x) over all sequences x of length n+m-1 that start with a1, a2, ..., ak. Therefore, the original problem reduces to finding the probability that a randomly generated sequence of length (n+m-1) contains no more than (m-1) “B”s, which is the second expression in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple induction on $m$ works. Indeed 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n+m}{k} &= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \left(\binom{n+m-1}{k} + \binom{n+m-1}{k-1}\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n+m-1}{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n+m-1}{k-1}\\
&= \binom{n+m-1}{m} + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{k}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\sum^{m}_{k=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(2^{m+1-k-1}\right) &= \sum^{m-1}_{k=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(2^{m-k}\right) + \binom{n+m-1}{m} \\
&= \binom{n+m-1}{m} + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(2^{m-k-1}\right)
\end{align}

Since for $m = 1$ the two quantities are equal to $1$.